# Good sites for basic class design?

Tags: c++

I am switching java to c++ and there is some fundamental difference that I am missing. If you guys know any good sites that have class design tutorial, please let me know. Stuff such as memory deallocation, things to avoid, etc.. I have also been googling this stuff but I just want more information. Maybe you guys can help. Thanks

Comment: I have found this useful: http://www.cplusplus.com/

Comment: Your question does not make sense? Class design is a high abstract, memory allocation is super low-level. Which is it you want?

Comment: lynda.com has an 11 hours C++ tutorial. http://www.lynda.com/C-training-tutorials/1250-0.html

Comment: This question is very general and is likely to be closed in its current state. Stack Overflow isn’t a forum. You would do well to make it more specific.

Comment: I just want more information on class design, mainly for beginners (maybe a little bit more advanced since I am familiar with programming). I will look at anything recommended.

Comment: Although you got some programming background and looking for a switch from Java to C++, it's really better if you start reading up tutorials on C++ and ask specific questions for the betterment of this website. Start from [Thinking in C++](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html).

Comment: YOu're missing a good book, good reference book (stroustroup?) and few years of practice. That's about it. For online reference cplusplusreference might do. Simply "googling" might not be a good idea - you need a book to learn C++.

Comment: Not a tutorial site, but I find [this reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) very useful. However, what you seem to be looking for is more of a general C++ tutorial site, as designing a program is language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [class design tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/class_design.html) found on the **CProgramming** website.